# Rasperry Pi won't boot any more after installing upstart

Tags: raspberry-pi, boot, upstart

I'm running Jessie 8.0 on a raspberry pi 2 B and it doesn't boot completely anymore after installing upstart

```
sudo apt-get install upstart
```

FYI: Apache, PHP, MySQL, KODI were installed upfront

What can I do? Could I try to uninstall upstart?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to boot again by removing upstart:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove upstart
```

This command will also automatically reinstall systemd-sysv

Comment: How do I run this when upstart is preventing me from booting?

Comment: RPi is not booting up :)

Comment: Just don't use you'r RPi to access the memory... Any laptop under Linux with SD card will do!!

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this headache this morning on my Raspberry Pi 3. You can use Recovery / Single User Mode to fix this.

- Plug in a keyboard and HDMI connection to the Pi.
- Repeatedly press shift while booting to get to the recovery console.
- Press 'e' to edit config, use tab and arrow keys to navigate to cmdline.txt
- Add "init=/bin/bash" to the end as the last argument
- Press "OK", and then hit the escape key to continue booting
- After the boot sequence looks like it has stopped (mine looked like it had frozen mid-boot, don't worry), try pressing enter to get a CLI prompt
- Type `/etc/init.d/mountall.sh`
- Type `mount -n -o remount,rw /` *(This mounts the root of SD Card)*
- At this point most commands should be functional, now you can use Escounda's answer and type: `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove upstart`

After a reboot everything should be back to normal with no OS reinstall required! Don't forget to remove "init=/bin/bash" from your cmdline.txt when you're finished.

Comment: This saved me, combined with this post for getting networking going: https://serverfault.com/questions/21475/starting-network-connection-from-ubuntu-recovery

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably late to the party, but I had the same issue yesterday (Pi won't boot, no way to use apt to remove upstart)

So I installed Ubuntu in a VM and chrooted into my SD Card (See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24011/13597 for more informations about this)

Then removed `upstart` just like in [Escounda's second post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34088873/3437046)